# Replacing values in a string with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Faced a simple task, but I can not solve. There is a table in df:

```
Date       X1   X2
02.03.2019  2   2
03.03.2019  1   1
04.03.2019  2   3
05.03.2019  1   12
06.03.2019  2   2
07.03.2019  3   3
08.03.2019  4   1
09.03.2019  1   2
```

And I need for rows where Date < 05.03.2019 set X1=NaN, X2=NaN:

```
Date       X1   X2
02.03.2019  NaN NaN
03.03.2019  NaN NaN
04.03.2019  NaN NaN
05.03.2019  1   12
06.03.2019  2   2
07.03.2019  3   3
08.03.2019  4   1
09.03.2019  1   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert column `Date` to datetimes and then set values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

df.loc[df['Date'] < '2019-03-05', ['X1','X2']] = np.nan
print (df)
        Date   X1    X2
0 2019-03-02  NaN   NaN
1 2019-03-03  NaN   NaN
2 2019-03-04  NaN   NaN
3 2019-03-05  1.0  12.0
4 2019-03-06  2.0   2.0
5 2019-03-07  3.0   3.0
6 2019-03-08  4.0   1.0
7 2019-03-09  1.0   2.0
```

If there is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y')

#change datetime to 2019-03-04
df.loc[:'2019-03-04'] = np.nan
print (df)
             X1    X2
Date                 
2019-03-02  NaN   NaN
2019-03-03  NaN   NaN
2019-03-04  NaN   NaN
2019-03-05  1.0  12.0
2019-03-06  2.0   2.0
2019-03-07  3.0   3.0
2019-03-08  4.0   1.0
2019-03-09  1.0   2.0
```

Or:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d.%m.%Y')

df.loc[df.index < '2019-03-05'] = np.nan
```

Comment: @anky_91 - ya, it working, because format `DD.MM.YYYY`. If change format like `MM-DD-YYYY` it failed. also should working `DDMMYYY`. Another formats failed.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use this solution, this is just another approach possible (-: (*this will affect all columns*)

```
df.mask(df.Date < '05.03.2019').combine_first(df[['Date']])
```

---

```
         Date   X1    X2
0  02.03.2019  NaN   NaN
1  03.03.2019  NaN   NaN
2  04.03.2019  NaN   NaN
3  05.03.2019  1.0  12.0
4  06.03.2019  2.0   2.0
5  07.03.2019  3.0   3.0
6  08.03.2019  4.0   1.0
7  09.03.2019  1.0   2.0
```